# Json response error in magento2

Tags: magento2.2.2

Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json warning in Chrome Developer Tools

How to fix this...

Answer (score 0):

This is an misleading error, chrome is actually saying it cant find that file. Go ahead and reploy static assets by `magento setup:static-content:deploy` or `magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` if in developer mode.

Comment: But the json response print directly in screen

Comment: what does the json say?

Comment: it returns ajax call response displayed in the screen.